# Normality test for non-independent observations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption, independence

I want to check if my data's distribution is normal. Thought of visual and formal test.

One thing I'm not sure about – my observations are respiratory measurements of patient. Each patient measure himself for 5 minutes (inhale, exhale). So the observations are not independent. Is it a problem preforming regular normality test (as I mention earlier)?
If so, what would be the solution?

---

tnx all for the answers. i want to check normality, because i want to present a summary value for every measurement (includes around 150 breaths), on a plot over time. so im triyng to decide if a the average will be good fit or maybe the median (?).

Comment: Why do you need to test for normality?

Comment: @utobi Don't we all hope for normal respiration?

Comment: If there was a good reason to do so, you could potentially test for multivariate normality (as long as you had enough data to do so), but for what purpose? Usually goodness of fit testing doesn't really answer a particularly useful question. It might be better to [describe what underlying issue led you to ask this specific question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @statsplease, I guess what we all hope for is ‘valid statistical inference’, being it under normality or any other comfortable modeling framework.